# Is there a Lemoon route for /{slug}

Tags: lemoon

I'm looking for an existing route (in Mindroute.Lemoon.Helpers.RouteHelper) that will already handle a path like http://www.mylemoonsite.com/blogpost3. It doesn't appear by requesting that URL that such a route is active, but it looks like some of the routes in RouteHelper.cs are attempting to cover that case. I can request http://www.mylemoonsite.com/blog/blogpost3, but I'm looking specifically for the former. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lemoon adds the catch-all route `{slug*}` to the end of the route-table, effectively catching everything that is not handled by other route handlers such as custom Controllers etc.

In order for Lemoon to respond to the request http://www.mylemoonsite.com/blogpost3 you need to have a page in your site with the permalink `blogpost3`. Since you get a response when requesting http://www.mylemoonsite.com/blog/blogpost3 I am guessing the permalink for your page is `blog/blogpost3`.

There are 2 things you can do to get a response from the path http://www.mylemoonsite.com/blogpost3.

- Edit the permalink of the page
- Add an alias to the page

If you add the alias `blogpost3` the page will respond to both http://www.mylemoonsite.com/blogpost3 and http://www.mylemoonsite.com/blog/blogpost3. When adding the alias you can also specify the HTTP response code for the alias (200 OK, 301 Moved or 302 Found).